# Android 12 popup over the keyboard (screenshot)

Tags: notifications, operating-system, popup

I'm having an issue with Android 12, on a Samsung Galaxy 22 Ultra.  It is showing some kind of popup over my keyboard and it sits there way too long so I can't continue with what I was doing and I have to wait for it to decide I've looked at it long enough.

[image: screenshot with red arrow pointing to the problem]

**I've turned off all the notification settings I can find.**
App Notification is OFF or everything not DM related
Alert when Clipboard Accessed is OFF

Searching the for solutions to the problem only shows me ways to turn of notification, which I have done.

How do I fix this?  Meaning, turn this off, or alter it so it's not in my way, or make it not display so long that I feel close to m*rder because it's stepping all over my flow.

Comment: It is called a Toast. You can turn off Toasts only if the app provides this as a feature or by using ADB or some power user app which offers this as a feature. But you need to find out first which app is creating that toast. If it is the app which is in the foreground of above image than see if there is a setting to turn off toast. Otherwise, see if this app is able to identify the toast. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree After that [this app](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) might be able to turn off toasts from the culprit.

Comment: @Firelord thank you for the suggestion and telling me what it's called, that has helped more than you can know!

Comment: No problem. Do self-answer whenever you manage to solve your question. :)